# How to extract number of currently opened tabs?

Tags: firefox, sqlite

I want to automatically count number of tabs that are open in Firefox so I can track this over time. It is not enough to get an add-on that displays current number in the browser.

From .sqlite tables Firefox saves for each profile I have not been able to decipher any table of currently opened tabs. I also looked for a column in the history table that tells whether page is currently open or not. Is this information available in the databases at all? If so, where is it stored? If not, how do add-ons like Tab Counter find this number?

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[How do I use Firefox' “sessionstore” files to restore my crashed session?](http://superuser.com/questions/394896)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Xidus: History and bookmarks are stored in the places.sqlite. You cannot determine tabs and windows information here.tabs and windows information are stored in the sessionstore.js  file.You can refer this links:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/sessionstore.js
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=622036&start=60&p=12098147#p12098147

Answer (score 74):

Open the `about:telemetry` link in Firefox and click `scalars` tab from the sidebar menu. Alternatively, opening `about:telemetry#scalars-tab_search=tab` will take you directly to the `scalars` tab.

The `browser.engagement.max_concurrent_tab_count` key will show the number of tabs active for the session, but does not update when a tab is closed. Instead, if you want to update this value you will need to restart your browser.

The `browser.engagement.tab_open_event_count` key shows the current number of open tabs at a given time and is updated dynamically.

Comment: This answer is nice since it is so simple. It seems to provide the maximum number of tabs which have been open which might not be the current number of tabs if you've closed any since reaching the high water mark.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Note that `browser.engagement.max_concurrent_tab_count` is reset for each session. If you want the "current" value, you can quit and restart.

Comment: I could be wrong (and clearly have a problem that I need to address....), but this value may cap at 1023 - I tried opening some additional tabs and refreshing, but did not see a higher value.
And this evening perhaps I should practice a bit of browser sanitation.

Comment: @fencepost: It doesn't cap at 1023, mine shows 1455. I closed some tabs and the value updated after *restarting* the browser (restart, not refresh the tab).

Comment: 1119 open tabs currently. Closing a few hundred seems in order.

Comment: The direct URL is `about:telemetry#scalars-tab_search=tab`.

Answer (score 14):

## Online

Within a running Firefox session, it's easy to extract the data using the Mozilla Add-on API. I wrote a simple [Tab Count Logger](https://github.com/mechanical-snail/tab-count-logger) extension that does this, and saves the count to an SQLite database.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
const windows = require("sdk/windows").browserWindows;

console.log("Windows: " + windows.length + "; tabs: " + tabs.length);
```

## Offline

Opened tabs are stored in `sessionstore.js` in the profile directory, not in SQLite. This file is JSON. A script to count tabs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Count open tabs from a firefox profile
# Working directory is the root of a Firefox profile.
import json
j = json.loads(open("sessionstore.js", 'rb').read().decode('utf-8'))
def info_for_tab(tab):
    try:
        return (tab['entries'][0]['url'], tab['entries'][0]['title'])
    except IndexError:
        return None
    except KeyError:
        return None
def tabs_from_windows(window):
    return list(map(info_for_tab, window['tabs']))
all_tabs = list(map(tabs_from_windows, j['windows']))
print('Statistics: {wins} windows, {tabs} total tabs'.format(wins=len(all_tabs), tabs=sum(map(len, all_tabs))))
```

After having saved this to `~/bin/firefox_count_tabs`, you can get the information for all your profiles as in:

```
for i in ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.*; do test -d $i && (echo "== $i =="; cd $i; ~/bin/firefox_count_tabs ); done
```

Comment: On current firefox versions that sessionstore.js file has been moved to sessionstore-backups/recovery.js - other than that your python script works fine. See also https://dutherenverseauborddelatable.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/firefox-the-browser-that-has-your-backup/

Answer (score 7):

You can count tabs in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (not Web Console) with:

```
gBrowser.tabs.length
```

The *Browser Console* is **disabled by default**. To enable it you can either:

1. Tick the option `"Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes"` in the Web Developer Tools settings.
2. Go to `about:config` and search for `devtools.chrome.enabled`, and toggle it to **true**.

After that look for *Browser Console* in the *More tools* menu, or open the *Developer Console* with `[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+J`, and you can now enter the above.

---

`option-1`

[image]

---

`option-2`

[image]

---

`[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+J`

[image]

Comment: Interesting but I get `gBrowser is not defined` even after restarting Firefox.

Comment: @DanDascalescu That's probably because you didn't do `[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+J` to open console. (There's no need to restart browser.) I've updated the above instructions.

Answer (score 4):

The count will be shown on the exit confirm dialog - if you hadn't disable that

update 2022-11-02: only when you have only one window

Comment: Those of us who use “Restore previous session” don’t have that enabled ;-).

Comment: In the current Firefox if you have more than one window open, the quit prompt will show the number of windows open, rather than the number of tabs.