# How can I get the number of Firefox windows currently opened?

Tags: firefox, xdotool

I tried `xdotool search --name firefox | wc -l`, but it shows wierd numbers like 8,11 or more, when only one windows is opened. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884363/in-mozilla-firefox-how-do-i-extract-the-number-of-currently-opened-tabs-to-save) what you are looking!

Comment: Is it possible to do this using xdotool?

Comment: Sorry, but i have not used xdotool for this. May be somebody else can help you out it xdotool is able to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the option --onlyvisible. Like this:

xdotool search --onlyvisible --name firefox | wc -l

It worked here. Maybe it could work for you too.